# SQL to return all records 18 months ahead of another date (to end of month)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, between

I have a table with two DATETIME fields, OpeningDate and FinishingDate.

I am trying to write a query that returns all records that have a FinishingDate that is exactly 16 months ahead of the OpeningDate.

I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM Sales
WHERE FinishingDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 16, OpeningDate)
```

But it appears to give me all records that fall between those dates (only up to the day in the month), I need it to get all records up until the end of the month.

So lets say I have an OpeningDate of 2017-10-6 (year, month, day) 18 months ahead would be 2019-04-06. This will only include records up to the 6th of April, I need it to include records up until the end of April.

What modifications can I make to the query to achieve this?

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your table structure along with the data, that would be better.

Comment: Use EOMONTH to convert your OpeningDate to the end of month : SELECT * FROM Sales
WHERE FinishingDate between  OpeningDate AND DATEADD(MONTH, 16, EOMONTH(OpeningDate))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code,

```
SELECT * FROM Sales 
WHERE FinishingDate between OpeningDate AND 
DATEADD(MONTH, 18, EOMONTH(OpeningDate))
```

Note :

```
DATEADD(MONTH, 18, EOMONTH(OpeningDate))
```

`EOMONTH` find the end of the OpeningDate and then `DATEADD` will add 18 months to that date. That will give exactly the end date of 18th month from that date.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this

```
SELECT * FROM Sales
WHERE FinishingDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 16, Convert(datetime,OpeningDate))
```

I tried it on my SQL server and it works fine with me.